# What German visa should my wife apply for to accompany me on a business trip?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan and have a German Schengen business visa, multiple entry valid for 2 years. Sometimes, when I travel to Germany for business, I want my wife to accompany me, so we do some sightseeing on the weekend. What visa category should my wife apply for?

Answer (score 3):

Since the ambitions of your wife are solely for sightseeing it should be fine to apply for a Schengen Tourist VISA. Welcome to Germany!

Also see [Schengen Visa Types](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/)